# Problem with a script that checks for a distribution name and does something depending on the distribution value

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to create a script that,depending on the distribution,runs a set of commands(in this example I want to check for Ubuntu and Centos). I've made a basic if-else statement in the script,but im new to bash and I can't understand why it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
  a= lsb_release -i | awk -F " " '{print $3}'


if  [ "$a"=="Ubuntu" ]; then
        echo "$a"       
else
        echo "Not ubuntu"
fi
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change it to a command: `a=$(lsb_release -i | awk -F " " '{print $3}')`

Comment: Put a shebang on your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: when you use `[` only a single `=` is used to compare strings for equality, so `if [ "$a" = "Ubuntu" ]; then`, look at `man [`. also look at the `-s` option of `lsb_release` which will give you just the information you want without header eg. `lsb_release -si`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. All of your answers helped me a ton in their own way. I fixed the problem and learned how to do it properly.  Thank you!